# Change URL in Fancybox, together with title

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I'm fighting a bit with Fancybox.  I'd like to change the URL for a picture after checking the status of the 'alt' attribute.

Here's my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({

      beforeShow : function() {
          var now   = new Date();
          var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
          var date  = now.getDate();
          var alt = this.element.find('img').attr('alt');
          this.inner.find('img').attr('alt', alt);
          if (month==11 && date >= alt){
             this.title = alt+'. Dezember'}
          else
          {this.title = 'zu früh'
          }
      }

});
});
```

That works fine for the title.

Now, I want to have another URL, other than the one received from the calling `href`.

I've tried this 'beforeLoad' already, and it doesn't work. Also, in this case, Fancybox doesn't appear.

What am I missing, or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You still can use `beforeLoad` and change the URL using `this.href` for the new address, so for this html:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.example.com">example</a>
```

use a script like:

```
var picssel = true;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeLoad: function() {
      if (picssel && picssel === true) {
        this.href = "http://picssel.com"
      }
    }
  }); // fancybox
}); // document ready
```

That will change the URL based on the validated variable

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yhkd23yg/)**